# Best approximation of a function on a infinite dimensional normed space in $L^2[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $L^2[-1,1]$ be the Hilbert space of real valued square integrable functions on $[-1,1]$ equipped with the norm $||f||$= ${\int_{{-1}}^1 ({|f(x)|}^2 dx})^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Consider the subspace $$M=\left\lbrace f \in L^2[-1,1] : \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx =0\right\rbrace$$ For $f(x)=x^2$, what is the value of $\inf \{||f-g|| : g \in M \}?$

I am trying to find best approximation of $f(x)$ on $M$. If $M$ would be finite dimensional then I know how to calculate best approximation but for infinite dimensional I am totally blanked how to find best approximation.

Comment: Can you compute the orthogonal projection $u$ of $g$ onto $M$, and then compute $\|g-u\|$?

Comment: Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017511/find-the-orthogonal-projection-of-a-function-on-the-set-of-l2-functions-whose).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$M$ is precisely the kernel of the linear functional on $L^2[-1,1]$ given by $f\mapsto \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \ dx $. Therefore, $M^{\perp}$ is a one dimensional space. Constant functions are orthogonal to $M$ and since they span a one dimensional subspace, $M^{\perp}$ is exactly the space of constant functions. Therefore,
$$x^2 = c + h$$

for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h \in M$. This forces $h = x^2 - c$. We can find  $c$ using that
\begin{align}
& 0  = \int_{-1}^1 (x^2 - c)\ dx = \int_{-1}^1 x^2   d x - 2c \\
\Longrightarrow \ \ \ \ & c = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1x^2 \ dx
 \end{align}
So $c = \frac{1}{6}$. We obtain our infimum by seeing that
\begin{align}
||x^2 - g||^2 &= ||(x^2 - c  - g) + c||^2 \\
 & = || x^2 - c - g||^2 + ||c||^2  \ \ \ \ (\text{By Pythagorean Theorem})\\ &  \geq ||c||^2
\end{align}
Therefore $||x^2 - g||^2$ is minimized if $||x^2 - c - g|| = 0$. This occurs when $g = x^2 - c$. 
So its minimum value is $||c||^2$.

Comment: I gave the wrong value of $c$ earlier. Off by a factor of $1/2$. lol